# Regular expression avoid unnecessary backtracking in Java

Tags: java, regex

Hello I am very new in the Regex world. I would like to extract the timestamp, location and the "id_str" field in my test string in Java.

```
20110302140010915|{"user":{"is_translator":false,"show_all_inline_media":false,"following":null,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/a\/1298918947\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","listed_count":0,"favourites_count":2,"verified":false,"time_zone":"Mountain Time (US & Canada)","profile_text_color":"333333","contributors_enabled":false,"statuses_count":152,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","id_str":"207356721","profile_background_tile":false,"friends_count":14,"followers_count":13,"created_at":"Mon Oct 25 04:05:43 +0000 2010","description":null,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","location":"WaKeeney, KS","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED",
```

I have tried this

```
(\d*).*?"id_str":"(\d*)",.*"location":"([^"]*)"
```

It has a lot of backtrack if I used the lazy quantifier `.*?` (3000 steps in regexbuddy), but the number of characters between the anchor "id_str" and "location" is not always the same. Also, it could be catastrophic if no location is found in the string.

How can I avoid
1) Unnecessary backtracking?

and

2) Faster to find non-match string?

Thanks.

Comment: What flavor of Regex are you using, or what programming environment ?

Comment: @RussC I used Java, added in the text. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like JSON: why not use a JSON parser for this?

Comment: @BartKiers It is a weird combination of a string and a JSON, also there are a lot of unwanted information in the text. So I would prefer regex.

Comment: It just looks like a timestamp, a pipe character, then JSON. I'd use a simple regex to extract the whole JSON and then use a proper JSON parser.

Comment: @Nick So that would be faster?

Comment: Yes - it would be a negligible difference in computing time, but a great improvement in development time. If the JSON is very large and you're critically concerned about performance, you can use an event-based parser API like the one offered by Jackson (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example)

Comment: I'm confused, if you just want some parts, why are you matching the whole string? Have you tried matching it three times, one for each data? There would be less backtracking, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
(\d*+)(?>[^"]++|"(?!id_str":))+"id_str":"(\d*+)",(?>[^"]++|"(?!location":))+"location":"([^"]*+)"
```

The idea here is to eliminate backtracks as much as possible using only [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) with restricted character classes (as you did in the last capture group)

Example, to avoid the first lazy quantifier, i use this:

```
(?>[^"]++|"(?!id_str":))+
```

the regex engine will take all characters that aren't double quotes as much as possible (and without register a single backtracks position because, a possessive quantifier is used), when a double quote is found a lookahead check if it is not followed by the anchor `id_str":`. All this part is wrapped by an atomic group (no backtracks possible inside) repeated one or more times.

Don't be afraid by the use of a lookahead inside which will fail quickly and only if a double quote is find. However you can try the same with a `i` if you are sure that it is less frequent than `"` (or a rare character before, if you find):

```
(?>[^i]++|i(?!d_str":))+id_str":(...
```

EDIT: the best choice here seems to be `,` that is less frequent: *(200 steps vs 422 with the double quote)*

```
(\d*+)(?>[^,]++|,(?!"id_str":))+,"id_str":"(\d*+)",(?>[^,]++|,(?!"location":))+,"location":"([^"]*+)"
```

To have better performances, and if you have the possibility, try to add an anchor (`^`) to your pattern, if it is the begining of the string or of a newline (with multiline mode).

```
^(\d*+)(?>[^"]++|"(?!id_str":))+"id_str":"(\d*+)",(?>[^"]++|"(?!location":))+"location":"([^"]*+)"
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your answer. I just debugged it and found out that each time a " is hit, a backtrack is performed. Is there anyway to avoid this? Can we just do a backtrack when "id_str" is hit?

Comment: @Seen: No, you can't totally eliminate the backtracks. How much steps?

Comment: @Seen: try with an anchor ^ if you can.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am learning regex and your example really help me.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like JSON and trust me it's pretty easy to parse it this way.

```
String[] input = inputStr.split("|", 2);
System.out.println("Timestamp: " + input[0]); // 20110302140010915

JSONObject user = new JSONObject(input[1]).getJSONObject("user");

System.out.println ("ID: " + user.getString("id_str")); // 207356721
System.out.println ("Location: " + user.getString("location")); // WaKeeney, KS
```

***Reference***:
[JSON Java API docs](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)