# .NET regex timing out in case of no match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a large string with following format:

```
{"_index":"2","_t":"g","_id":"3","_source":{"Id":3,"C":3,"PortfolioIdList":[1,3,4],"TISList":[1,2]}
,"sort":[3000]}
```

The PortfolioIdList could be either empty `[]` or have numbers in it like shown above. The idea is to insert another number into PortfolioIdList if and only if it contains numbers i.e. it is not empty. I have written a regex for this which is timing out. The regex is:

```
const string STR_REGEX = @"(\{"")(_)(index"":)(.*?)(""_id"":"")([0-9]*)("")(.*?)(\{.*?""PortfolioIdList"":\[(?!\]))([^\]]*)(\][^\}]*)((.|\r|\n|\r\n|[^\}])*\},)";
var myRegex = new Regex(STR_REGEX, RegexOptions.None);
var strTargetString = File.ReadAllText(@"raw1.txt");
const string STR_REPLACE = @"${1}${3}${5}${6}${7}${8},""_parent"":""${6}""}}\r\n${10}${11},2344${12}\r\n";
var newStr = myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, STR_REPLACE);
```

The regex works properly in case the list is not empty, however it times out when the list is empty, something like `"PortfolioIdList":[]`. I am really not sure what is wrong with my regex, any help will be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Note: You can also verify the regular expression yourself quite comfortably with online services such as [Regex101](http://regex101.com/).

Comment: I think there is a default timeout in `.net`, the point is that regex takes too long to execute i.e. to say that it did not find a match in the given string.

Comment: @elgonzo I have already verified my regex on those services and it works over there, however, specifically in my .net code it fails. The exception says that there might be too much backtracking in my regex.

Comment: @Babbupandy, ah yes. I stand corrected. Sorry for the mistake :)

Comment: That looks like [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Have you tried deserializing the JSON string to an in-memory C# class representation, making your changes, then serializing back? I think we're missing the context on whether you're using WCF or WebAPI. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a JSON and we are trying to optimise insertion into this text, serialising/deserialising and looping through the list takes time and hence we decided to go with the regex route. The performance has improved for cases where the list is not empty, however, for empty list the regex times out :(

Comment: @elgonzo I have tried to remove the greedy matches as much as possible.

Comment: Not sure whether it is related to your problem, but your regex should not match for `"PortfolioIdList":[]` because of the negative look-ahead at `""PortfolioIdList"":\[(?!\])`.

Comment: Perhaps replace `(\{.*?""PortfolioIdList"":\[(?!\]))([^\]]*)` with `(\{.*?""PortfolioIdList"":\[)([^\]]*?)`

Comment: I just understood the problem, since the large file contains only the empty list, the engine keeps backtracking to the last match on the first line after it reaches the end of every line, therefore looping a large number of times. Now if only I could figure out a way to optimise it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem I had was that in case of no matches, the regex expression kept backtracking to the first line (in thousands of lines of text) and this took unusually large amount to compute.

I solved the problem following way:

1. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255291/regular-expression-avoid-unnecessary-backtracking-in-java) helped me a lot to remove unnecessary backtracking
2. I used [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92ad728f-ff6f-4ff5-a2bc-0b2182f59e7e/using-conditional-regex-in-c?forum=regexp&prof=required) MSDN post for conditionally replacing the text